# How do I uninstall Linux?

Tags: linux-mint

I want to uninstall Debian based Linux Mint from my hard drive. I have so many packages on this laptop that I don't use anymore, I want to put this laptop on Windows 8. I know how to install Windows 8, I just need to uninstall Linux Mint.

My laptop's specs are as follows if it matters for some reason:

Samsung NP300E4C-A02US
CPU: Intel i3-2350M
RAM: 4GB of DDR3
Storage: 500gb HDD

Comment: Windows Installer give you the option to format a partition or even re-partition the whole disk

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that

- there is no content you want to keep from Linux
- there was no highly-sensitive data on Linux which would require a secure disk wipe

then there's nothing you need to do on the Linux side.  When installing Windows, just have the installer use all the disk space, erasing pre-existing partitions.

Comment: Thank you for the help, but I've actually decided to keep the laptop on Linux Mint due to me being locked out of my BIOS, and the internal HDD is taking priority of booting over my USB and DVD/CD drive. I tested your solution on a different pc that had Linux Mint on it. I wanted that on Windows so I only didn't have to download two versions of an app.

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sda bs=1M count=100 ; sudo sync ; sudo shutdown -h now;
```

Comment: Will  sudo, sync, and shutdown still work after you have clobbered the partition table? Did you check this yourself? :)

Comment: @xenoid yes I have done this before, errrors depend on cache, but that is why I use semicolon instead of ampersand.